# Templated Interface - create a generic template class to return any container

Tags: c++, c++11

My idea is to create a template out of interface such that it can return any container:

```
template <class T>
class IValue {
public:
    virtual I& get() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Value : public IValue<T>
{
public:
    Value() :m_value()
    {}
    virtual T& get() const override
    {
        return m_value;
    }
    virtual ~Value()
    {}
private:
    T m_value;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
};

int main()
{
    Value<A> a1;
    //a1.get();
}
```

But I get compilation error as mentioned below:

```
 $ c++ -std=c++14 try52.cpp
    try52.cpp:4:17: error: 'I' does not name a type
             virtual I& get() const = 0;
                     ^
    try52.cpp: In instantiation of 'class Value<A>':
    try52.cpp:32:10:   required from here
    try52.cpp:14:16: error: 'T& Value<T>::get() const [with T = A]' marked override, but does not override
         virtual T& get() const override
                    ^
    try52.cpp: In instantiation of 'T& Value<T>::get() const [with T = A]':
    try52.cpp:34:1:   required from here
    try52.cpp:16:16: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'A&' from expression of type 'const A'
             return m_value;
```

How can I design or implement such a functionality?

---

Thanks for the comment I got this working but is it a right design:

```
template <class T>
class IValue {
    public:
        virtual const T& get() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Value : public IValue<T>
{
public:
    Value() :m_value()
    {}
    virtual const T& get() const override
    {
        return m_value; 
    }
    virtual ~Value()
    {}
private:
    T m_value;
};

class A
{
public:
   A(){}
};

int main()
{
   Value<A> a1;
   a1.get();
}
```

Comment: What's unclear about the compiler error? You never introduced a type `I` anywhere.

Comment: In main when I am creating instance of Value with type A will it not know the T during compile time?

Comment: "How can I design or implement such a functionality?" you do not. You need to better understand how C++ works. When you do you will also understand that your idea is wrong. Many novice programmers come up with this idea though.

Comment: @Programmer Of course `T` will be known at compile time, `I` won't.

Comment: Solution: `using I = T;` \*scnr\*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that - corrected the same - please let me know if my design has any issues

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  You've basically just re-invented `const` variables.  Were you trying to implement something akin to `std::any`?

Comment: My requirement is that I need to create an interface which should return different objects at runtime meaning the type with which it has been instantiated - hence it can return Objects of class A - B etc but then the receiver should actually be able to modify the objects and call a function that accepts an Interface

Comment: Seems to be a [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Programmer I think we need an actual example (in a separate question) of what you want to achieve.  As is, an `IValue<T>` will only ever store a `T` and doesn't really offer any benefit over using a `const T` or `const T&` directly.  It sounds like you want either type erasure or polymorphism, but I'm not entirely sure which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing your typo on line 4 (`I` instead of `T`) your compiler will tell you that it cannot convert from `const T` to `T&` at the return statement of `T& get() const`.

Since your `get()` is `const`-qualified, the `this`-pointer will point to a `const` object inside the function. You cannot use a non-`const` reference to refer to a non-`mutable` member of a `const` object.

Either don't `const`qualify `T& get()` or have it return a reference to a `const T`: `T const& get() const`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that - corrected the same - please let me know if my design has any issues

Comment: `mutable` is another option.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Edited to mention `mutable`. Other thing: What is the usual course of action if a question is changed in a way that renders allready given answers obsolete?

Comment: @Swordfish Rolling back the edits is the most usual way.